# How to check if target triplets are compatible?

Tags: gcc, rust, compiler-construction

I have a legeacy project at my hands, which runs on old and fairly limited hardware. I thought of rewriting the rather small project in rust, since the old source is pretty hard to maintain.

My question is: How can I compare two target triplets to judge the compatibility of rust with the old hardware?

From the rust docs I know, that the compiler supports the target `i586-unknown-linux-gnu`.
And we currently compile the old `c` based source with `i586-suse-linux` as the target using gcc.
I suspect, that unknown would include any vendor. But the latter part I am not really sure - even after googling for quite a bit.

Is there any way to know for sure?

Comment: What happens if you simply try? Start with an empty main, and if that works, add incrementally each functionality. You will have unit tests and integration tests, won't you? -- You could use "ldd" to see dependencies on libraries.

Comment: Are you cross-compiling, or do you plan on compiling on the machine? What version of GCC, what version of SUSE?